# Combining two maps - is it this ugly?

Tags: haskell

Today I had two maps I needed to combine: `consMaps :: Map k a -> Map k b -> Map k (a, b)`.  Seeing nothing in Data.Map, I set out to implement this and came up with something unexpectedly ugly:

```
consMaps :: Map k a -> Map k b -> Map k (a, b)
consMaps ma mb = mapMapMaybe g (Map.unionWith f a' b')
  where
    a' :: Map k (Maybe (Maybe a, Maybe b))
    a' = fmap (\a -> Just (Just a, Nothing)) ma
    b' :: Map k (Maybe (Maybe a, Maybe b))
    b' = fmap (\b -> Just (Nothing, Just b)) mb
    f :: Maybe (Maybe a, Maybe b) -> Maybe (Maybe a, Maybe b) -> Maybe (Maybe a, Maybe b)
    f (Just (Just a, _)) (Just (_, Just b)) = Just (Just a, Just b)
    f (Just (_, Just b)) (Just (Just a, _)) = Just (Just a, Just b)
    -- f (Just a, Just b) _ = Just (a, b) -- impossible in this context
    -- f _ (Just a, Just b) = Just (a, b) -- impossible in this context
    f _ _ = Nothing
    g :: Maybe (Maybe a, Maybe b) -> Maybe (a, b)
    g (Just (Just a, Just b)) = Just (a, b)
    g _ = Nothing


mapMapMaybe :: (a -> Maybe b) -> Map k a -> Map k b
mapMapMaybe f mp = snd (mapEither (maybe (Left ()) Right . f) mp)
```

Am I missing something?  Is this as good as this gets?

Comment: Shouldn't the type be `Map k (Maybe a, Maybe b)`?

Comment: It could be, I'm not sure if it should be.

Comment: Well, given two maps `m1 :: Map k a` and `m2 :: Map k b`, what should the result of looking up a given key in `consMap m1 m2` produce? Specifically, what should you get for `key` if 1) `key` is in both maps 2) `key` is in one map but not the other, and 3) `key` is in neither map?

Comment: Are you sure that this code produces the correct result? It does not type check for me. It seems like you would need an `Ord` constraint (which implies `Eq`). If you cannot compare the keys for equality, it seems like this operation would necessarily have to be a bit strange (probably with outputs that have multiple entries with the same key).

Answer (score 13):

It looks like your `consMaps` implementation, with the signature you've given, is just

```
consMaps :: Map k a -> Map k b -> Map k (a, b)
consMaps = intersectionWith (,)
```

If instead you wanted a `Map k (Maybe a, Maybe b)`, I might write that as

```
consMaps :: Map k a -> Map k b -> Map k (Maybe a, Maybe b)
consMaps ma mb = unionWith combine ma' mb' where
  ma' = fmap (\ a -> (Just a, Nothing)) ma
  mb' = fmap (\ b -> (Nothing, Just b)) mb
  combine (a, _) (_, b) = (a, b)
```

Comment: Or rather `consMaps = merge (mapMissing $ \_ a -> (Just a, Nothing)) (mapMissing $ \_ b -> (Nothing, Just a)) (zipWithMatched $ \_ a b -> (Just a, b))`?

Comment: @HTNW: where are those methods coming from?  None of them are in Data.Map as far as I can tell.

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.5.1/docs/Data-Map-Merge-Lazy.html#v:merge

Comment: This looks good, but `k` requires an `Ord` constraint

Comment: @HTNW: you can post that as a separate answer, but I've got to admit I find my version easier to read.

Comment: The advantage of `merge` here is performance. Mapping over a large map is fairly expensive, so fusing things together tends to be a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

If you want `Map (a, b)` out then use the other answer (`intersectionWith`). If you want a `Map (Maybe a, Maybe b)` then that specialized function won't work. Instead, `containers` has a `merge` function, which covers "basically all" ways to combine `Map`s. It takes three strategies: what to do if a key is only in the left map, what to do if a key is only in the right map, and what to do if a key is in both. The strategies are built using helper functions. The idea is that `merge` does exactly one traversal of the inputs, so is more efficient than e.g. mapping the inputs and then combining.

```
import Data.Map.Merge.Lazy

catMaps :: Ord k => Map k a -> Map k b -> Map k (Maybe a, Maybe b)
catMaps = merge left right both
  where left  = mapMissing $ \_ a -> (Just a, Nothing)
        right = mapMissing $ \_ b -> (Nothing, Just b)
        both  = zipWithMatched $ \_ a b -> (Just a, Just b)
```

Note that the "right" type for the output in this version is actually `Map k (These a b)`, where [`These`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-1.1.1.1/docs/Data-These.html#t:These) models "inclusive or":

```
data These a b = This a | That b | These a b
theseMaps :: Ord k => Map k a -> Map k b -> Map k (These a b)
theseMaps = merge left right both
  where left  = mapMissing $ const This
        right = mapMissing $ const That
        both  = zipWithMatched $ const These
```